# bottom border disappearing if using a hexadecimal notation for the background color

Tags: css, hex, border, background-color

I was trying to simply apply a 1px solid border all around an anchor tag with a certain "dark" background color expressed as a hexadecimal value and I noticed that the bottom border was not there!

After quite a long investigation I was surprised in seeing that the problem was caused by the background color expressed in hexadecimal: apparently in this case the browser starts to render the background 1px lower than the correct position and the result is that the background color overlaps the bottom border and if the background color is darker than the border color then the result is that the bottom border color "disappears".

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ze5xopj/1/) trying to describe this behavior:

```
  HTML
  <a href="#" id="a1">ANCHOR1</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" id="a2">ANCHOR2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" id="a3">ANCHOR3</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" id="a4">ANCHOR4</a>

CSS
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
a, div {
  width:95%;
  padding-left:5%;
  display:block;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#a2, #d2 {
  background-color:yellow;
}

#a3, #d3 {
  background-color:#00ffb6;
}

#a4, #d4 {
  color:white;
  background-color:#1769b6;;
}
```

1. tag with no background color: you see the border correctly all around it
2. tag with background color defined with the name of the color: the border is still all around the tag
3. tag with light hexadecimal background color: you see that the border is there but the background color starts to be rendered 1px lower overlapping the bottom border
4. tag with dark hexadecimal background color: the bottom border looks "disappeared"

I am using Mac El Capitain 10.11.6 and tried with:

- firefox 51.0.1
- chrome  56.0.2924.8
- safari  10.0.3

all of them behave n the same way.

Any idea how to obtain a full 1px solid border around an element with a background expressed in hexadecimal?

The issue is not related to the anchor tag as I prove in the fiddle applying the same style to divs.

[image]

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me on Chrome on Windows 10.  Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, bottom border is there like @KyleMartin stated. I'm using Chrome on Windows 10, but you could just simply convert hex to decimal! It's not hard, and as long as you know the format Red Green Blue, you can probably do it in under 5 minutes! Then again, there are calculators for this.

Comment: I can see the border bottom, try to add box-sizing: border-box see if it's make any different.

Comment: @Ty Q: I tried RGB as well it does not make any difference unfortunately ..

Comment: I definitely seeing different things, have you try other browser?

Comment: @LucaBorrione have you tried specifically setting the border-bottom property?

Comment: @LucaBorrione With "!important" at the end to reinforce the styling property?

Comment: @LucaBorrione border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

and defining a slightly thicker border-bottom-width